# Prevent IHP RunDevServer from automatically opening a window or tab

Tags: ihp

Is there a way to start the server without it automatically opening a tab? Something similar to `webpack serve --no-open`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `IHP_BROWSER` environment variable to `echo` before running the dev server:

```sh
export IHP_BROWSER=echo
./start
```

This is described in the IHP recipes:

https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/recipes.html#dont-autoopen-the-app-in-the-browser

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little more to the accepted answer.

The answer can be found on the [Recipes](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/recipes.html) page in the Documentation along with other helpful best-practice solutions. Another solution is to append `export IHP_BROWSER=echo` to the local `.envrc` file.

```
// .envrc
PATH_add /nix/store/...
export IHP_BROWSER=echo
```